# How to configure gulp-sass properly?

Tags: sass, libsass

Here is my gulpfile.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

// Gulp Sass Task
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    console.log('called');
  // gulp.src locates the source files for the process.
  // This globbing function tells gulp to use all files
  // ending with .scss or .sass within the scss folder.
  gulp.src("scss/*.scss")
    // Converts Sass into CSS with Gulp Sass
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    // Outputs CSS files in the css folder
    .pipe(gulp.dest("css"));
});

// Watch scss folder for changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  // Watches the scss folder for all .scss and .sass files
  // If any file changes, run the sass task
  gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.{scss,sass}', ['sass'])
});

gulp.task("transpile", function () {
  return gulp.src("js/*.js")
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./compile"));
});

// Creating a default task
gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'transpile']);
```

gulp sass runs successfully but does not create any css folder which I am expecting. Also when I run the sass manually,

```
sass --trace  _picker.scss:css/_picker.css
```

I see the css being compiled properly. Not sure what is going wrong with gulpfile. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if the CSS folder is already created? What do you see in the terminal?

Comment: Did you try "gulp.dest("./css")" ?

Comment: weird part is I don't get any errors on terminal. Even when I have manually created css folder, I don't get compiled css from sass()